# How do I get Jenkins stash/bitbucket notifier to mark the PR verified?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I got the jenkin pull request builder and stash notifier working but all it does is add a comment to the stash pr saying the build status. What I would like is for jenkins user to be a required reviewer and mark the code changed Reviewed (check mark for the required Jenkins user).

Is there s way to do this or is my line of thinking wrong and I should handle this another way?

High-level, what I want to do is make it a requirement for merge for the PR build to be successful. The comment by it self doesn't do that

Answer (score 0):

inside the repo configuration page in stash, under "pull requests" select "merge checks" enable the "Minimum successful builds" setting and set to the number of build you require to be successful for the merge to be allowed.